# How to prevent to delete specific character with bacspace key

Tags: c#

I want to write temperature in my textbox for example:"38.8". But I dont want to use maskedTextbox.

My code:

```
  private void textBox_TextChanged() 
  {
     if(textbox. text. length() == 3)
     {
       textbox. Text += "." ;
     } 
  }
```

But it doesnt work. I would like that the backspace key avoid comma. How to do that?

Comment: - Hint: Regex...

Comment: *But it doesnt work* - indeed. It won't even compile with that camel casing of the properties, and treating length like a method when it isn't. when it's syntactically correct you'll have a problem with that length=3 part.. 38.8 does not have a . added after the number has reached 3 long

Comment: Ok but I dont know how to do programarly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the **best way** but will do the job. You can use **KeyPress** event for your textbox

```
        private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
            if ((e.KeyChar != (char)System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Back))
            {

                if ((sender as TextBox).Text.Length == 2)//set dot(.) after 2 numbers.
                {
                    (sender as TextBox).Text += ".";
                    (sender as TextBox).SelectionStart = this.Text.Length;
                }
            }
        }
```